# Event listener vs subscriber in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, events

I get to know from documentation that subscriber already knows what should it subscribe to, but now I am in doubt that when defining listener we provide exact event when it should be fired like this

```
kernel.listener.my_listener:
    class: myBundle\EventListener\MyListener
    arguments:
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        - @twig
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: myMethod}
```

So the listener exactly knows when to fire off
But in case of subscriber we register it like this

```
kernel.listener.my_listener:
    class: myBundle\EventListener\myListener
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Now, my question is how would subscriber know when to trigger or does it get triggered on every event??

Comment: While building the container during the Symfony compile phase, static method Subscriber::getSubscribedEvents() is called and the results used to register the listener.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subscriber has a list of events - the `getSubscribedEvents()` method. It is in fact, only that method, flagged by the EventSubscriberInterface that requires it, that defines that a class is an event subscriber.

It is called during startup (when the container is being compiled) which then builds the listeners from the events that are subscribed to.

[Using Event Subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#using-event-subscribers)